# Is there any way this ODE can be solved with variation of constants?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'' - y' = \frac{2-x}{x^3}e^x$$

The solution of the homogenous equation is $C_1 + C_2e^x$.

Now, onto the variation of parameters:

In this case, the Wronskian would simply be $e^x$. Therefore, we get

$$C_1' = -\frac{e^x(2-x)}{x^3}$$ and

$$C_2' = \frac{2-x}{x^3}$$

However, I can't calculate $C_1$ in terms of standard mathematical functions. The integral is too complicated and every integral solver I tried gives me back some of the non-standard functions we haven't learned about.

The exercise specifically says to solve this problem with the use of variation of parameters so I think I may have made a mistake, or there's an easier way to solve the integral.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can probably reduce $C_1$ via partial integration so that only a multiple of $\int\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx$ remains. This is a known integral that has no further symbolic simplification.

Comment: @lutz the "multiple of $\int (e^x/x)dx$" you describe turns out to be zero times that integral.  See the answers for various ways to cancel out the nonelementary terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you tried to integrate the $e^x/x^n$ terms separately you may have had a little problem.  Such integrals cannot be rendered as elementary functions for any positive $n$.

But render this:

$C_1'=\color{blue}{\frac{-2}{x^3}}\color{brown}{e^x}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{x^2}\color{brown}{e^x}}$

The blue factors satisfy $(1/x^2)'=-2/x^3$ and the brown ones satisfy $(e^x)'=e^x$ -- so $C_1'$ is actually the product-rule form for the derivative of $e^x/x^2$!  You can therefore integrate accordingly.

What happened to the nonelememtary terms I referred to in the $e^x/x^2$ and $e^x/x^3$ integrals?  They are still there for the separate integrals, but they cancel out when they are combined to form the antiderivative of $-e^x(2-x)/x^3$.

Comment: Oh wow, this is something I never would have realized on my own. I definitely have to start seeing integrals as antiderivatives because this is the second time I missed them

Answer (score 3):

$$y'' - y' = \frac{2-x}{x^3}e^x$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$(y'e^{-x} )' = \dfrac{2}{x^3}-\dfrac 1 {x^2}$$
Then integrate both sides.
$$y'=e^{x} \left ( -\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac 1 {x}+C \right)$$

$$y' = \left ( \dfrac{1}{x}e^x\right)'+Ce^x$$

This  is easy to integrate.

Comment: When I do this integration I still get $e^x/x^n$ terms in the second integration.  While we know now that the nonelementary functions cancel out leaving an elementary result, this answer is complete only if it explicitly shows this cancellation.

Comment: then on the RHS you just have $(e^x\dfrac 1x)'$  @OscarLanzi  this should be easy to integrate again.

Comment: Thanks, I know this already. What we need is to put this result into the answer for the broader audience, including the OP.

Comment: I added a line in my answer @OscarLanzi